# SDL while running loop glitch. Why is the if statement making the SDL window not render properly

Tags: c++, sdl

If the number inside the if statement is changed to anything less than 40 the program will start rendering the SDL window correctly does anyone know why is this happening?? thanks in advances.

```
while(this->running) {
    SDL_PollEvent(&event);
    if(event.type == SDL_QUIT) {this->running = false;}

    currentTime = SDL_GetTicks();

    //changing the 40 on the if statement below
    //to any other number less than 30 
    //will make the program run correctly. I'm not sure why 
    //this is happening. help!!!
    if(currentTime > lastTime + 40) {
        SDL_UpdateTexture(
            this->texture,
            NULL,
            this->pixels,
            this->WIDTH * sizeof(Uint32)
        );

        for(int i = 0;i < HEIGHT;i++){
            for(int j = 0;j < WIDTH;j++){
                this->pixels[i*WIDTH + j] = DSDL_MapTanhToRGB(fmt,1000000/(pow(i-HEIGHT/2,2) + pow(j-WIDTH/2,2)+100*(int)loopCount+1));
            }
        }

        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

        //printf("Loop #: %d\n",loopCount);
    }

    lastTime = currentTime;
    loopCount++;
}
```

Ultimately what I'm trying to do with the if statement is to lower the frames per second to use cpu resources somewhere else.

Comment: Think about how often `lastTime` is updated where it is now. Do you think maybe it belongs inside the if?

Comment: yes yes it does. didn't see that. thanks.

Comment: You might consider setting `nextTime = currentTime + 40;` and `if(currentTime > nextTime) ... ` It might make the frame rate more stable if the time to render tends to vary.